# Form field loses input focus on typing

Tags: reactjs, underscore.js

I am working on implementing the following `double`, which the user can input: `Account Details` & `Account Currency`.

The data is retrieved from the server in the following format:

```
{
  ...,
  "invoiceConfiguration": {
    "id": 290271069734815,
    "bankConfigs": [
      {
        "bankDetails": "Bank Details Euro",
        "currency": {
          "id": 17592186045607,
          "name": "Euro",
          "iso": "EUR"
        }
      },
      {
        "bankDetails": "USD Test Bank details",
        "currency": {
          "id": 17592186045610,
          "name": "US Dollar",
          "iso": "USD"
        }
      }
    ]},
    ...
}
```

I implement the following in my `render()` function.

Bank Accounts

```
    {_.map(this.state.company.invoiceConfiguration.bankConfigs, (bankConfig, i) => {
      return (
        <div className="row" key={_.uniqueId("bankDetailRow_")}>
          <div className="small-12 medium-6 columns">
            <label>
              Account Details
              <textarea rows="6" value={bankConfig.bankDetails} onChange={event => this.onBankDetailsChange("bankDetails", i, event.target.value)} />
            </label>
          </div>
          <div className="small-12 medium-4 columns">
            <label>
              Currency
              <Select
                name="bankCurrency"
                placeholder="Bank Account Currency"
                value={bankConfig.currency.id}
                options={currencyTypeOptions}
                onChange={_.partial(this.onBankDetailsChange, "currency", i)} />
            </label>
          </div>
        </div>
      )
    })}
```

The `onBankDetailsChange()` function is defined as follows:

```
onBankDetailsChange(key, pos, val) {
    if (key === "currency") {
      val = {
        id: val.value
      };
    }
    const company = this.state.company;
    let bankAccounts = company.invoiceConfiguration.bankConfigs;
    bankAccounts[pos][key] = val;
    company.invoiceConfiguration.bankConfigs = bankAccounts;
    this.setState({
      company,
      status: "unsaved"
    });
  }
```

Each time I type something, the input field loses focus.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Answer from here: http://reactkungfu.com/2015/09/react-js-loses-input-focus-on-typing/

In our case, the offending code is here:

`<div className="row" key={_.uniqueId("bankDetailRow_")}>`

Since the `key` is unique, each time the state it throws away the old div and adds a new div in its place. It looks identical, but it looses the focus.

The solution is to use a `key` which does not change. Here, this works:

`<div className="row" key={i}>`